# How can i broadcast native message to more than one browser using ProcessID in .Net core 3.1 C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

[.Net core 3.1 C#]
[this set of code send message only current process]

```
    string sendingData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, utils.GetJsonSerializerSettingCamelcase());
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendingData.ToString());
    Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 0) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 8) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 16) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 24) & 0xFF));
    stdout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stdout.Flush();
```

I build a console application in .Net core 3.1 with c# and create .EXE for this application. It's using by extension which is loading in Edge/Chrome/Firefox. This code working fine when communication initiated by browser.
Now I want to send message to all browser extension, but it sends only current process.
I get all process ID
`Process[] processes =  Process.GetProcessesByName("ConsoleApp");`
but i fail to send message to all process.

```
Process[] utilityProcess =  Process.GetProcessesByName("ConsoleApp");            
        foreach(Process p in utilityProcess)
        {
            
            
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"Process ID {p.Id.ToString()} Process Name {p.ProcessName}");
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"SendMessage:{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)}");
            string sendingData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, utils.GetJsonSerializerSettingsCamelCase());
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendingData.ToString());
            
            Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 0) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 8) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 16) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 24) & 0xFF));
            stdout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stdout.Flush();
            
        }
```

in the above code `Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();` hold the reference of current process. But i want  `Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();` hold the reference of p process.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please don’t post your code as an image

Comment: You can copy your code and past it here as code block, you can take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) Have you tried debugging your code? How many process is returned from the "GetProcessesByName" VS how many successfully received your "message"?

Comment: @Mahmoud I got three process. 
1. Chrome
2. Edge
3. Firefox
but this will send 3 messages to chrome only.. becouse Process.GetCurrentProcess() returns chrome process

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here, but the foreach variable `p` which is the current process in the current iteration is not being referenced by your code

Comment: If I did understand what you are trying to do, [Process.StandardInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=netcore-3.1) is what you are looking for. You can write directly to the input stream of another process that way.

Comment: You are only sending 'p' to the logger and not using it in your stream.

Comment: Side note: "broadcast native message" in Windows means something very different that what your code shows - [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) is what your title means for many people who used/programmed in Windows...  Also writing to standard input does not necessary going to reach your code as console input is read-once...